# $\lim_{x \to 3} x^2$, Clearly the value is 9, How can we be sure of this in an infinite precision system such as a number line(i.e infinite zoom)?

Tags: limits

My question is: on a number line which has infinite precision i.e can be infinitely zoomed, so now as we approach 3(x->3), we approach closer to 9, here if we approach infinitesimally close we get infinitesimally close to 9, but in a system as this which has infinite precision even infinitesimal values can't be appropriated to zero(such as 0.00000...1) and if I try to understand this with epsilon and delta definition a chain of reasoning is formed(Apologies if I have incomplete Information) where I get to a small interval, I get a small enough value to approximate but then the graph can be zoomed again and this continues again and again and we never actually get 9 then how and why can we write 9 in a case such as a graph on a phone or computer which can be infinitely zoomed?
In other words how does the limit win against the infinite zooming?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a limit is:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta>0:|f(x)-L|<\epsilon \quad\forall x \in (x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$$

then $\displaystyle \lim_{x\mathop\to x_0}f(x) = L$.

This definition allows for any $\epsilon$, no matter how small it is. If the graph is zoomed again, we find a new $\delta$ satisfying this, and we can always find that $\delta$ provided that the limit exists.